# Sum over rows (rollapply) with time decay

Tags: r, time, sum, data.table, rollapply

This is a follow on question to a question I posted earlier (see [Sum over rows with multiple changing conditions R data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172732/sum-over-rows-with-multiple-changing-conditions-r-data-table) for more details). I want to calculate how many times the 3 subjects have experienced an event in the last 5 years. So have been summing over a rolling window using `rollapply` from the `zoo` package. This assumes that the experience 5 years ago is as important as the experience 1 year ago (same weighting), so now I want to include a time decay for the experience that enters the sum. This basically means that the experience 5 years ago does not enter into the sum with the same weighting as the experience 1 year ago.

I my case I want to include an age dependent decay (even though for other applications faster or slower decays such as square root or squares could be possible).

For example lets assume I have the following data (I build on the previous data for clarity):

```
mydf <- data.frame (Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005,
                         2007, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003,
                         2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2007),
                Name = c("Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Fred", "Gill",
                         "Fred", "Gill", "Gill", "Tom", "Tom",
                         "Fred", "Fred", "Gill", "Fred", "Gill", "Gill"))

# Create an indicator for the experience 
mydf$Ind <- 1

# Load require packages
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

# Set data.table
setDT(mydf)
setkey(mydf, Name,Year)

# Perform cartesian join to calculate experience. I2 is the new experience indicator 
m <- mydf[CJ(unique(Name),seq(min(Year)-5, max(Year))),allow.cartesian=TRUE][,
        list(Ind = unique(Ind), I2 = sum(Ind,na.rm=TRUE)),
        keyby=list(Name,Year)]

# This is the approach I have been taking so far. Note that is a simple rolling sum of I2
m[,Exp := rollapply(I2, 5, function(x) sum(head(x,-1)), 
                align = 'right', fill=0),by=Name]
```

So question now is, how can I include a age dependent decay into this calculation. To model this I need to divide the experience by the age of the experience before it enters the sum.

I have been trying to get it to work using something along these lines:

```
 m[,Exp_age := rollapply(I2, 5, function(x) sum(head(x,-1)/(tail((Year))-head(Year,-1))), 
                     align = 'right', fill=0),by=Name]
```

But it does not work. I think my main problem is that I cannot get the age of the experience right so I can divide by the age in the sum. The result should look like the `Exp_age` column in the `myres` `data.frame` below

```
myres <- data.frame(Name = c("Fred", "Fred", "Fred", "Fred", "Fred", 
                         "Gill", "Gill", "Gill", "Gill", "Gill", "Gill", 
                         "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom"), 
                Year = c(2003, 2004, 2004, 2006, 2007, 2000, 2001, 2005,
                         2005, 2006, 2007, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003), 
                Ind = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                Exp = c(0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4), 
                Exp_age = c(0, 1, 1, 1.333333333, 1.916666667, 0, 1, 0.45, 
                            0.45, 2.2, 2, 0, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 2.833333333))
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to do a `rollapply` with `width=5` and rather than do a simple sum, you want to do a weighted sum. The weights are the age of the experience relative to the 5 year window. I would do this: first set the key in your `data.table` so that it has proper increasing order by `Name`, then you know that the last item in your `x` variable is the youngest and the first item is the oldest (you do this in your code already). I can't quite tell which way you want the weights to go (youngest to have greatest weight or oldest) but you get the point:

```
setkey(m, Name, Year)
my_fun = function(x) { w = 1:length(x); sum(x*w)}
m[,Exp_age:=rollapply(I2, width=5, by=1, fill=NA, FUN=my_fun, by.column=FALSE, align="right") ,by=Name]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. You are right that is what I try to achieve. I have adjusted the function to suite my needs as `my_fun = function(x) {w = length(x):1; sum(x/w)}` and this seems to return the correct values (or at least some) but the the `Exp_age` column does not align as expected. Plus I get 3 warning message saying: `1: In ``[.data.table``(m, , ``:=``(Exp_age, rollapply(I2, width = 5, by = 1,  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 13 in column 'Exp_age' (recycled leaving remainder of 4 items).` (Cont. next comment)

Comment: `2: In ``[.data.table``(m, , ``:=``(Exp_age, rollapply(I2, width = 5, by = 1,  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to group 2 of size 13 in column 'Exp_age' (recycled leaving remainder of 4 items).
3: In ``[.data.table``(m, , ``:=``(Exp_age, rollapply(I2, width = 5, by = 1,  :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to group 3 of size 13 in column 'Exp_age' (recycled leaving remainder of 4 items).` Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: I think I found what was going wrong. I have to allow `partial = TRUE`. So the code is: `m[,Exp_age:=rollapply(I2, width=5, by=1, FUN=my_fun, by.column=FALSE, align="right", partial = TRUE), by=Name]`. I then just have to lag the experience variable to get to the desired result (I could not get it to do it in one go though).

Comment: what you need is to have `fill = NA`, not `partial=T`. that will make sure the returned vector is the same length as the original `data.table`. i edited my answer