# Calculate running sum/decay value in time series

Tags: r, time-series, rollapply

I'm looking to calculate a specific type of 'diminishing' sum or decay value within a time series.

For instance, say I have some simple data:

```
thedata <-  data.frame(magicseeds = c(30,20,10,40,20)
                     ,week = seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1))
```

I would like to calculate the value of 'magicseeds', such that it has a diminishing impact over time. For instance, lets say each value has 20% of the value the following week, so the first value in the magicseeds column (30) would be 30*0.2+6*0.2 and so on until the time series ends(=7.488). The calculation for the last value (20) would be 0 as it is the last value in the time series.

The filter function is close, but is a cumulative sum that takes into account the total time series eg.

```
thedata$filtervalues <- with(thedata, as.numeric(stats::filter(magicseeds, filter=0.2, method="recursive")))
```

I've been testing out the rollapply function as well with little luck.

Final output would be this:

```
 magicseeds week filtervalues  calculation
1     30    1        7.488     sum(30*.20^1, 30*.20^2, 30*.20^3, 30*.20^4)
2     20    2        4.96      sum(20*.20^1, 20*.20^2, 20*.20^3)
3     10    3        2.4       sum(10*.20^1, 10*.20^2)
4     40    4        8.000     sum(40*.20^1)
5     20    5        0.000
```

**UPDATE:**
This question has more or less been answered here:
[Iterate and sum a calculation across rows by varying row position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406009/iterate-and-sum-a-calculation-across-rows-by-varying-row-position)

Comment: Could you make sure your expected output uses values in the example data? Where does `10.5` in `30*0.2+10.5*0.2` come from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708477/sum-over-rows-rollapply-with-time-decay

Comment: Sorry, used wrong decay filter, have updated question.